# Return struct as void

Tags: c++, structure

I'm having a function that returns a a void data. And i need to receive it as a structure.
eg. say a structure widget_data. a function GetObjectData() that returns a void data.

```
widget_data *wd=GetObjectData();
```

and `GetObjectData()` returns `sd->data`.

where `sd` is structure, data is of `void` type.

when i compile it i get error message like

```
invalid conversion from void* to widget_data*
```

Comment: Not void data, but a void pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clarify things a little first. `void` means nothing, so you cannot have a data of void type. Thus, if function returns `void` then is cannot possibly return any data. Now, the `void *` is a void pointer. You can treat it as a memory address pointing somewhere. It could be pointing to any kind of data, or even nowhere. If you are pretty sure that your function returns a pointer to `widget_data` object, then you can do a [reinterpret_cast](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/). For example:

```
widget_data *wd = reinterpret_cast<widget_data *> (GetObjectData ());
```

If you are not that sure, you have to check the type of data returned. That might be possible if RTTI is enabled (it is usually enabled by default) and base class has at least one virtual method. Then you can use [dynamic_cast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_cast). If that is not possible, you have to come up with some custom way of checking the return type.

Comment: You can use a static_cast to go from voidptr just as well, but other than that this answer explains nicely :)

Comment: @nj: yes you can! Since both `reinterpret_cast` and `static_cast` here will do the same thing, I prefer `reinterpret_cast` as it gives more idea to whoever reads the code that there is a strong assumption and not very strong type checking, which indicates a possibly very dirty hack. But yeah, technically both will do the job.

Answer (score 6):

`static_cast` can convert `void*` to a pointer to a specific type:

```
widget_data* wd = static_cast<widget_data*>( yourVoidPointer );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
widget_data *wd=(widget_data *)GetObjectData();
```

or

```
widget_data *wd=reinterpret_cast<widget_data *>(GetObjectData());
```

Comment: +1, as `reinterpret_cast` is a better idea. On coding aspect, conversion from `void*` should look **dirty** and, `reinterpret_cast` is dirtier than `static_cast`.

Answer (score 1):

This is valid C, but not valid C++.  You need an explicit cast in C++, such as

```
widget_data *wd = static_cast<widget_data *>(GetObjectData());
```